# Some good controls and examples to chart functions

Tags: c#, wpf, math, charts

Some good controls and examples to chart functions

I am looking for some examples of plotting functions with some code and seeing that on a chart

so If I had a function like

y=x^2+2

I want to see that plotted from say 0 to some really high number.

C# (WPF in VS 2010 maybe) would be ideal or if their is some other library that works well for this that is fine.

Comment: I looked at Visfire and I saw there is something in the WPF toolkit (which I don't see in VS 2010).

I was hoping for an example (not a full blown project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPlot will do it and it is free. I have found the initial learning curve is a little steep compared to other options (although it is more powerful too).
http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/

This one might be promising as well - not sure what they use internally but you could find out fairly quickly.
http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/entry5094.aspx

http://graphingcalculator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks interesting. Do you have a line plot example. I did not see one (documentation for this thing appears to need some work, and has spam in the wiki)

Answer (score 1):

[Visifire](http://visifire.codeplex.com/) on codeplex is pretty good and is GPL2 licensed, if you want to use WPF. To Evaluate expressions you might need to an Expression evaluation library like [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/) (licensed LGPL) along with the charting one.

Answer (score 0):

[WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) is Better and Simple. 
You might consider this free charting controls